# R: Creating first-differences for combination of group and non-group

Tags: r, data.table

I have this `data.table` that has some group specific data, and some general data:

```
         group year      flow      agg
   1: 51557094 2010   3.46000 592649.6
   2: 51557133 1999 111.60000 522706.2
   3: 51557133 2000  29.36000 555279.7
   4: 51557133 2003  96.38000 592649.6
   5: 51557193 2004  65.22000 550622.4
```

`flow` here is `group`-`year` specific, and `agg` is `year` specific. I would like to compute first-differences: For `flow` based on `group`, and first-differenced along `year`, and for `agg` no grouping, just first-differencing along `year`.

I'd prefer approaches not including `dplyr`.

#### Expected Output

```
         group year     dFlow      dAgg
   1: 51557094 2010        NA        NA
   2: 51557133 1999        NA        NA
   3: 51557133 2000    -82.24   32573.5
   4: 51557133 2003        NA        NA
   5: 51557193 2004        NA  -42027.2
```

Comment: "I'd prefer approaches not including `dplyr`." Now you tell me.

Comment: Use data.table chaining!

Comment: Maybe add how your desired output should look like too.

Comment: @akrun rows `2`, `3` are successive years and the same group: both have group `51557133` and the years are `1999` and `2000`.

Comment: @akrun: Oh, I am using the wrong language then. What I mean is: I want to group by `group` and first-difference along `year`. For `agg`, there's nothing to group about, just first-difference along `year`.

Comment: @akrun I tried to keep the question as simple as possible, hence no `log` prior to first-differencing in the procedure.

Comment: @akrun You probably correctly did not get my values - I apparently made a mistake when manually computing the differences. Sorry for that! I'd already award you with a bounty for all the trouble I'm costing, but thats not possible yet.

Comment: @akrun: `dAgg` is the first-difference of agg along `year`: `dAgg[2000] = agg[2000] - agg[1999]`, `dAgg[2004] = agg[2004] - agg[2003]`. Since there's no observation on the previous year value of `agg` for other years of the sample, its `NA` for the remaining fields.

Comment: I updated with a possible option (still needs some tinkering though), Can you check it.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
 library(data.table)
 myDataTable[, ind:= 1:.N][order(year)][seq_len(.N) %in% 1:2, 
            dFlow:=c(NA, diff(flow)) , by = group][,
            dAgg:= c(NA, diff(agg)), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(year)!=1))][
               order(ind)][,3:5 := NULL][]
  #      group year  dFlow     dAgg
  #1: 51557094 2010     NA       NA
  #2: 51557133 1999     NA       NA
  #3: 51557133 2000 -82.24  32573.5
  #4: 51557133 2003     NA       NA
  #5: 51557193 2004     NA -42027.2
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(group = c(51557094L, 51557133L, 51557133L, 
51557133L, 
51557193L), year = c(2010L, 1999L, 2000L, 2003L, 2004L),
flow = c(3.46, 
111.6, 29.36, 96.38, 65.22), agg = c(592649.6, 522706.2, 555279.7, 
592649.6, 550622.4)), .Names = c("group", "year", "flow", "agg"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", 
"5:"))

myDataTable <- as.data.table(df2)
```

Comment: @FooBar  Could you update your post with the expected output.  I used `eipi10s` output as reference

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` approach. First we apply `diff(log(agg))` to all the data, then we use `group_by(group)` to apply `diff(flow)` by `group`.

```
library(dplyr) 

dat %>% arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(diffAgg = c(NA, diff(log(agg)))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(diffFlow = c(NA, diff(flow)))

     group year   flow      agg     diffAgg diffFlow
1 51557133 1999 111.60 522706.2          NA       NA
2 51557193 2004  65.22 550622.4 0.052029728       NA
3 51557133 2005  29.36 555279.7 0.008422676   -82.24
4 51557094 2010   3.46 592649.6 0.065131380       NA
5 51557133 2010  96.38 592649.6 0.000000000    67.02
```